# angular: Error: Unknown provider during module.config()

Tags: angularjs

I get `Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: testProvider from myApp` in the below code:

`test` is a custom provider.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(function (testProvider) {
    testProvider.setPrefix("works: ");
  });
```

Full code is here:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(function (testProvider) {
    testProvider.setPrefix("works: ");
  });


angular.module('myApp')
  .provider ("test", function () {
    var prefix;
    this.setPrefix = function(p) {
      prefix = p;
    }

    this.$get = function () {
      return {
        log: function(msg) {
          console.log (prefix + msg);
        }
      }
    }
  });

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller ("myCtrl", function($scope, test) {
    $scope.$watch ('myModel', function (newval) {
      test.log(newval);
    })
  });
```

Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/zcIHRn?p=preview

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A call to

```javascript
module.provider("test", ...);
```

is really a call to

```javascript
module.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.provider("test", ...);
});
```

(See my [wiki article on dependency injection](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection) for more details.)

And since `config` blocks run in the order they were declared, you just need to move the declaration of your provider to above the point where it's used. You'll often see it written something like this:

```javascript
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .provider ("test", function () {
    var prefix;
    this.setPrefix = function(p) {
      prefix = p;
    }

    this.$get = function () {
      return {
        log: function(msg) {
          console.log (prefix + msg);
        }
      }
    }
  })
  .config(function (testProvider) {
    testProvider.setPrefix("works: ");
  })
  .controller ("myCtrl", function($scope, test) {
    $scope.$watch ('myModel', function (newval) {
      test.log(newval);
    })
  });
```

An example: http://plnkr.co/edit/AxTnGv?p=preview

If you really want to keep the concerns separate, you can create a new module and set up a dependency:

```javascript
angular.module('logging', [])
  .provider ("test", function () {
    var prefix;
    this.setPrefix = function(p) {
      prefix = p;
    }

    this.$get = function () {
      return {
        log: function(msg) {
          console.log (prefix + msg);
        }
      }
    }
  })

angular.module('myApp', ['logging'])
  .config(function (testProvider) {
    testProvider.setPrefix("works: ");
  })
  .controller ("myCtrl", function($scope, test) {
    $scope.$watch ('myModel', function (newval) {
      test.log(newval);
    })
  });
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/PWtDFG?p=preview

Comment: Came here looking for how to get a value injected into the config call on the module and found the answer in the wiki link. I had previously read that config blocks could only be injected with providers and constants, I had just never heard of constants before. I just assumed they were no different than values. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Note the difference between the provider registered name (`test`), its name when configuring (`testProvider`), and the invocation name (`test`). I cannot remember reading that in the API. I'll post here if the reference shows up.

Comment: I was pulling hairs from my head to make my provider work, and it was as easy as create the provider before using in config

Comment: Why is it that you inject the testprovider when you declared it as just test. it makes no sense to me since the name "testProvider" isnt referenced anywhere, why does angular work like that?

Comment: @SjoerddeWit You're defining a *service* named `test`, which is obtained by calling the `$get` method (which Angular does automatically when you inject `test`). If you want the *provider*, and not the service, you can access it with `testProvider` (literally just the word "Provider" appended to the service name). See [my answer on dependency injection](https://github.slack.com/archives/tech-talk-women/p1464716164000488) for more details.

Comment: Yes thank you,I read some more about it and it made sense when I read that the others are just syntatic sugar on top of the provider. Still I was left wondering. Instead of assigning values, can you also use a provider to do a simple check for let's say if a user is authenticated or isn't? I just saw people using it to preset config variables, but it would make sense to configure a different go-to state if a user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I created an enhanced example based on Michelle's first example, hope it could be helpful.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.provider('aPro', function() {
    console.log('provider initialized');

    this.config = function() {
        console.log("provider config");
    };

    // provider constructor
    this.$get = function() {
        console.log('provider constructor');
        return {
            log: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        };
    };
});

/* service act like factory with */
myApp.factory('aFac', function() {
    console.log('factory initialized');

    return {
        log: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    };
});

myApp.directive("test1", function() {
    console.log("test1 directive setup");

    return {
        compile: function() {
            console.log("directive compile");
        }
    }
});

myApp.directive("test2", function() {
    return {
        link: function() {
            console.log("test2 directive link");
        }
    }
});

myApp.run(function() {
    console.log("app run");
});

/* highlight! need add provider in config need suffix 'Provider' */
myApp.config(function(aProProvider) {
    console.log("app config");

    aProProvider.config();
});

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, aFac, aPro) {
    console.log("app controller");
    aFac.log("factory log");
    aPro.log("provider log");
});
```

link: http://jsfiddle.net/zhangyue1208/ysq3m/1826/